# redirect chrome users in new window

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I have [tried this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/642-Open-new-window-Asp-NET-way.aspx) but its not what I want ....
also this code does not works

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Paypal", "HowItWorksRedirect", null, new { @class = "Paypal" })%>

 public ActionResult HowItWorksRedirect()
 {
     return Redirect("https://www.paypal-deutschland.de/sicherheit/schutzprogramme.html");
 }
```

I want to redirect all chrome users to new window
I want to keep users on my website but also redirect them to new window... (600x800 or something like this)

How can I do that?

Comment: i want that on redirect code <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/">

Answer (score 0):

Opening a new window (or tab, depending on browser settings) is easy:
With a link, you can use

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">LINK</a>
```

Or you can [use JS](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp):

```
window.open('http://google.com', 'Google', 'width=800, height=600');
```

With the help of `navigator.userAgent` you can get the User Agent and use a regex to find out if the user is using Chrome

```
if(/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { /* CHROME USER */ }
```

Comment: thanks i know that but i want new tab in 301 redirect code  <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/">

Comment: Ahm, ok, then I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>



//specify page to pop-under
var popunder="http://wow.ge/"

//specify popunder window features
//set 1 to enable a particular feature, 0 to disable
var winfeatures="width=800,height=510,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,toolbar=1,location=1,menubar=1,status=1,directories=0"

//Pop-under only once per browser session? (0=no, 1=yes)
//Specifying 0 will cause popunder to load every time page is loaded
var once_per_session=0

///No editing beyond here required/////

function get_cookie(Name) {
  var search = Name + "="
  var returnvalue = "";
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
    if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists
      offset += search.length
      // set index of beginning of value
      end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
      // set index of end of cookie value
      if (end == -1)
         end = document.cookie.length;
      returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
      }
   }
  return returnvalue;
}

function loadornot(){
if (get_cookie('popunder')==''){
loadpopunder()
document.cookie="popunder=yes"
}
}

function loadpopunder(){
win2=window.open(popunder,"",winfeatures)
win2.blur()
window.focus()
}

if (once_per_session==0)
loadpopunder()
else
loadornot()

</script>
```

but browsers blocking that !